# can we access the managed code with out pointer object?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

i have created some application in managed c++.when i try to instantiates it shows error as

cannot convert from obj to *obj. when i instantiates as pointer obj it shows no error.

so. is there any way to access such class without creating pointer object

Comment: Could you add a code snippet to show what you mean a little more clearly?

Comment: Please remove the c#.net tag.

Comment: C# removed from tags. Next question: is this Managed C++ (as in the question text) or C++/CLI (as in the tags)? They are two completely different things and totally change the interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The question says you're using Managed C++, and the tags say you're using C++/CLI (available in VS 2005 or later). You'll probably have a less confusing time with C++/CLI.

If that's what you're using, then there are two ways to "translate" from C#. Suppose you have some C#:

```
// Construct
MyClass c = new MyClass();

// Call some method
c.MyMethod();

Console.Writeline(c); // will call ToString on MyClass

// Finished with it
c.Dispose();
```

You can write this in C++/CLI like this:

```
MyClass ^c = gcnew MyClass;

// Call some method
c->MyMethod();

Console.Writeline(c); // will call ToString on MyClass

// Finished with it
c->Dispose();
```

The variable `c` is called a "handle", not a pointer, declared with ^ instead of *. Also we have to use `gcnew` instead of `new`. This is the same thing as a reference variable in C#, and is analogous (but not identical) to a pointer in C++, so we use `->` to access members.

Or you can write it like this:

```
// Create with local scope
MyClass c;

// Call some method
c.MyMethod();

Console.Writeline(%c); // will call ToString on MyClass (note the %)
```

First thing to note: we declare it in the style of a local C++ variable. There is no need to explicitly `gcnew` the object. Secondly, we treat the object as if it was a local variable (or a C++ reference to such a variable). So we use . instead of `->`. Thirdly, we can "convert" this local object into a handle, by prefixing it with `%`, which acts like the .NET equivalent of `&` that we use with ordinary pointers. It means "take the address of" or "give me a handle to" an object. Finally, we don't have to call `Dispose` on the object. The compiler does that for us at the end of the scope in which we declared it, as the `Dispose` method is the mechanism by which destructors are implemented in C++/CLI.

Comment: can I make this
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()); ??

Comment: Yes, if c is an object (as in third code example). ToString() returns a handle (System.String ^) which is what WriteLine accepts. If c is a handle, you'd need to put c->ToString().

Answer (score 0):

You could create it on the stack.

```
MyObject foo;
foo.bar();   // accessing bar method on object foo
```

Maybe the syntax you are looking for is this:

```
MyObject *foo = new MyObject;
foo->bar;
```